# JQuery Mobile : submit form

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, form-submit

I developp a mobile website with Jquery Mobile. I have a [form sending mail](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt6j0c5o43yo9ls/bug_jquery_mobile2.png). By clicking "send", there is a pop up indinquant loading the page. This pop-up does not disappear. 
[image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybjxuktgz3lq8yl/bug_jquery_mobile1.png)
But the mail is sent. I do not see how settle this problem. Thank you for helping me.

Edit: link image 2

Comment: the link to your image2 is broken...

Answer (score 0):

$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "close" )

see the jQueryTutorial documentation :
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Comment: The pop up is displayed automaticaly by jquery mobile when i submited the mail.